# What does the "\\A" delimiter do in the following Http Request code?

Tags: java, android, http

So I'm following this Android app dev course on Udacity and I'm confused.
  The following function  returns a JSON, but I don't understand the usage of the delimiter ("\A").

```
  public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

So what the \A delimiter does? How does it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`useDelimiter(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) method takes a regex pattern as parameter.

Regex patterns are **documented** in the javadoc of the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

The `\A` pattern is listed in the [Boundary matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) block:

> `\A` - The beginning of the input

This basically specifies that there is no delimiter, so the `next()` method will read the entire input stream.

The question code is equivalent to the following code using the [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    String content = IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    return (content.isEmpty() ? null : content);
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this explanation for a day....now I understand everything

Comment: I have never seen or heard about this, both an interesting question and good answer. +1 from me

Comment: hasNext() checks if there is next (second) token in the input stream and it will block waiting for it. And as there can't be more than one beginning of string it will block indefinitely.

Comment: @grzegorz Calling `hasNext()` before calling `next()` for the first time, means "has first", and will return `true`, assuming there is at least one character in the input. After calling `next()`, which would have consumed the entire input, calling `hasNext()` will return `false`, since end-of-input has been detected. `hasNext()` will not block indefinitely.